# significance of confidence intervals: how to know when the confidence intervals are significantly diffeernt from each other?

Tags: plot, confidence-interval, significance

In my effect plot I have 2 treatments and their confidence intervals.
How can I know when the difference between the groups (treatments) aren't significant anymore based on the confidence intervals plotted??
aka: based on the calculated 95% confidence limits, I need to see until when the 2 treatments remained statistically significant..
Thanks!
[image]